# How to have Apache have /robots.txt lead to a file, regardless of Domain?

Tags: apache, apache2, robots.txt

I run a Local server with the following URLs:

```
foo.self
bar.self
blah-blah.self
```

The above URL is handled by the following `VirtualHost` statement:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName self
    ServerAlias *.self
    VirtualDocumentRoot C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\%-2
   <Directory C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\*>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Each has their own `/robots.txt`, but what i need to do have any of the URL's return the exact same thing no matter what their `/robots.txt` contain or even if it does not exist.  In example, the following URLs:

- foo.self/robots.txt
- bar.self/robots.txt
- blah-blah.self/robots.txt

...will return the same text:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This is without resorting to a 301 `Redirect` or `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make an Alias for /robots.txt inside your hosts configurations pointing to the same file. Plus maybe a Location directive is required to grant access:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName self
    ServerAlias *.self

    Alias /robots.txt C:\Somfolder\robots.txt
    <Location "C:\Somfolder\robots.txt">
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Location>

    VirtualDocumentRoot C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\%-2
   <Directory C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\*>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You add this to *all* hosts configuration, all those `Alias` directives point to the same file. THe file `C:\Somfolder\robots.txt` is a "normal" robots.txt file as you described it.

---

You can simpify this by including that directive as a pattern. That way you place the directive inside a separate configuration file and only add an include directive to your hosts configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName self
    ServerAlias *.self

    Include C:\path\to\file\robots.inc

    VirtualDocumentRoot C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\%-2
   <Directory C:\Users\Foo\PhpstormProjects\*>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

File `C:\path\to\file\robots.inc`:

```
Alias /robots.txt C:\Somfolder\robots.txt
<Location "C:\Somfolder\robots.txt">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

---

*Note that I have next to no knowledge about MS-Windows systems. So the example paths I noted down may not make sense. But you should be able to get the idea :-)*

Comment: So that was what the `Alias` keyword was for!  Appreciated, it works as expected.